# View doesn't allow null value

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I have a view that show the data of several different object.

```
CREATE VIEW viewA AS
    SELECT
        fiel1, field2, field3, -- table 1
        field4, field5, field6, -- table 2
        field7, field8 -- table 3
    FROM table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id
       JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.t3id = t3.id
GO
```

My tables are the following :

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   id      int not null IDENTITY(1, 1),
   field1  int not null IDENTITY(1, 1),
   field2  int not null,
   field3  int not null,
   t2id    int, -- foreign key, is nullable
   t3id    int  -- foreign key, is nullable
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
   id      int not null IDENTITY(1, 1),
   field4  int not null,
   field5 int not null,
   field6 varchar not null
);

CREATE TABLE table3 (
   id      int not null IDENTITY(1, 1),
   field7  int not null,
   field8 varchar not null
);
```

When I populate table1 with some data and nothing in the t2id, the view is not populated with the data, even though the id itself is not mandatory. When I complete the fields and add some id in t2id, the data is correctly displayed. I tried to use the isnull function in `isnull(field7, null) as field7` but that doesn't change anything.

So, is it possible to have a view that display null value, even if the field itself is not nullable but the references is ? (I also tried with the field nullable and it didn't work).

Comment: *"When I populate table1 with some data and nothing in the t2id, the view is not populated with the data"* no, it won't be, you have an **`INNER JOIN`** in the `VIEW` definition. So rows *must* be present in the tables `table1`, `table2` and `table3`. Are you, perhaps, after a `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a JOIN clause. Use a LEFT JOIN instead

```
CREATE VIEW viewA AS
    SELECT
        fiel1, field2, field3, -- table 1
        field4, field5, field6, -- table 2
        field7, field8 -- table 3
    FROM table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id
       LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.t3id = t3.id
GO
```

Learn more about SQL Joins here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot !